# Возвращает null

Tags: php

Когда пользователь входит в аккаунт, ему выводятся вся его информация. Username выводится, а email нет. Решил я проверить через var_dump и мне вывелось NULL. Почему? Помогите пожалуйста. Прошу вас

```html
// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);

  if (empty($username)) {
   array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
   array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
   $password = md5($password);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $rows = mysqli_query("SELECT 'email' FROM 'users' WHERE 'email'='$email' ");
    $email_user = mysqli_fetch_array($rows);
   $results = mysqli_query($db, $query, $rows);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['email'] = $email_user['email'];
     $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
     header('location: index.php');
   }else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
   }
  }
}
```

```html
// Настройки
<?php 
  session_start(); 

  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Вы должны зарегистрироваться";
    header('location: login.php');
  }
  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: login.php");
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <h2>Настройки</h2>
    <a href="settings.php">Настройки</a></span>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <!-- notification message -->
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
      <div class="error success" >
        <h3>
          <?php 
            echo $_SESSION['success']; 
            unset($_SESSION['success']);
          ?>
        </h3>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

  
    <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
        <p>Имя пользователя <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
        <p>Email <strong><?php var_dump($SESSION); echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></strong></p>
        <p>Текущий пароль <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['password']; ?></strong></p>
        <p> <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Теперь разберитесь когда в mysql запросах требуется использовать кавычки, а когда нет. А когда следует использовать бэктики.

Comment: @u_mulder да я увидел, что у меня не там кавычки и исправил, но все равно не работает

Comment: Что исправили, где? Тут нет телепатов,  отредактируйте вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Когда вставляете переменную PHP в запрос или в любой другой текст вы должны обернуть его в фигурные скобки или использовать конкатенацию чтобы корректно его выявить

```
$rows = mysqli_query("SELECT 'email' FROM 'users' WHERE 'email'='". $email ."' ");
```

или

```
$rows = mysqli_query("SELECT 'email' FROM 'users' WHERE 'email'='{$email}'");
```